# Can I add ICO functionality to a final contract code?

Tags: ico

I'm thinking to add ICO functionality directly to my final contract code. Is it worth it? It's just compares time. If current time is > than ICO time, then it's works like a normal project and all ICO functions are disabled. Asking because i'm afraid to do something wrong.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Moreover, personal note, don't tell me you have a white paper and want to make monney with ICO...

Comment: @Andromelus Why? What is the problem with launching an ICO? I'm not trying to make money.

Comment: But this is the purpose of an ICo...